# DiscordJS Detecting when a User joins a guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMemberAdd => {
  console.log("Guild Member joined");
});
```

I know I have some noob error please help lmao, Just trying to simply detect when a user joins a guild/server and give them a certain role.

Comment: is this all your code or is there more? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

A couple ways of adding the roles. Either by id or by role. It's better to know the role ids as it will be faster, however you can look up the role by name as well.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    // Set the member's roles by id
    member.setRoles([/* role id here */]);

    // Don't know the role id?
    const role = guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'your role name');
    member.addRole(role);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just testing this code and it already works. Just have someone join your channel and you'll see that message in your console.

Comment: Ah channel, I was trying to see if i worked for when a user joined the guild lmao, Also yes there is more code.

Comment: arent guilds the same as channels? This code snippet suggests that.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs on [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd), you can see that the parameter returned in the function is actually a `GuildMember` (you put `guildMemberAdd`, probably because you didn't know what was passed into that callback).

From there, you can just use [`Guildmember.setRoles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setRoles) to give that member / user a specific role.

Try something like this:

```
// the parameter of the callback function is a `GuildMember` class, so name the variable
// something reasonable like 'guildMember', not 'guildMemberAdd'
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    // Set the member's roles to a single role
    guildMember.setRoles(['<your role id>'])
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more? This seems uh I don't know, Complex.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit weird if you didn't look at the docs or don't have much experience reading API docs. Do you understand what a `GuildMember` is? and my comment about your `guildMemberAdd` parameter?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond been busy, Yeah I understand what a GuildMember is and I completely understood the guildMemberAdd part. Sorry so for my code I would change the part after the comma to "GuildMember" ?. Thats what I got so far?

Comment: Now I'm sorry for the delay - did you fix it up? I added some sample code that might work for you - just make sure you have a specific role `id` you want to set on guild members, and put that where I have `'<your role id>'`